# Is it valid to place ad below Youtube Thumbnail view in Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-youtube-api

One of my app was **rejected** by google play as it displayed **ad** below the youtube player.

This time my app contains a listview (**containing Youtube Thumbnail View as image and a title**). I am thinking of placing an ad below the listview. **So is it valid?**

Comment: 1. I'm not sure that this is a valid topic for Stack Overflow (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but there is  a history of questions about submission, so...

Comment: 2. Is there any chance you can post more information about when/why/how you were rejected before? Did Google Play link any documentation annotating why you were violating TOS, etc ?

Comment: The app was rejected as ads were placed below the youtube player which is violation of the policy. @jesses.co.tt